# Simple Grep Mismatch problem

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line, grep

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and using Grep to process some HTML files.

Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<a href="video.php?video=one-hd.mov"><img src="/1.jpg"><a href="video.php?video=normal.mov"><img src="/2.jpg"><a href="video.php?video=another-hd.mov">
```

I would like to extract `one-hd.mov` and `another-hd.mov` but ignore `normal.mov`.

Here is my code:

```
example='<a href="video.php?video=one-hd.mov"><img src="/1.jpg"><a href="video.php?video=normal.mov"><img src="/2.jpg"><a href="video.php?video=another-hd.mov">'
echo $example | grep -Po '(?<=video.php\?video=).*?(?=-hd.mov">)'
```

The result is:

```
one
normal.mov"><img src="/2.jpg"><a href="video.php?video=another
```

But I want

```
one
another
```

There is a mismatch there.

Is this because of the so-called **Greedy** Regular Expression?

I am sing GREP but any command line bash tools are welcome to solve this problem like sed etc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As per the usual answer, do not EVER try to match HTML with a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Marc B then I should use what to process HTML. Actually Grep if gr8 for HTML processing.

Comment: Grep is great for FINDING things. But the only thing that can handle HTML properly is a DOM parser. Anything else will just turn around to bite you at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want use Perl regexes for grep - why not directly perl?

```
echo "$example" | perl -nle 'm/.*?video.php\?video=([^"]+)">.*video.php\?video=([^"]+)".*/; print "=$1=$2="'
```

will print

```
=one-hd.mov=another-hd.mov=
```

Comment: I know. The secret is `[^"]`. The following works too: `echo $example | grep -Po '(?<=video.php\?video=)([^"]+)(?=-hd.mov">)'`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using xmlstarlet:

```
$ example='<a href="video.php?video=one-hd.mov"><img src="/1.jpg"><a href="video.php?video=normal.mov"><img src="/2.jpg"><a href="video.php?video=another-hd.mov">'
$ echo $example | xmlstarlet fo -R 2>/dev/null | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//*[substring(@href, string-length(@href) - 6, 7) = '-hd.mov']" -v 'substring(@href,17, string-length(@href) - 17 - 3)' -n
one-hd
another-hd

$
```

Comment: You even have to count the characters?`substring(@href,17, string-length(@href) - 17 - 3)`? It is not as convenient as grep.

Comment: @DocWiki: But it is more fail-safe. You can of course replace the numbers with string-length() functions and static values or check which other string functions xmlstarlet supports. This is just an example on how to work with it. You can also combine xmlstarlet and grep, using xmlstarlet to just extract the href-attributes and use grep to get the filenames that you want if you feel more comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using awk:

```
{
    for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {
        if ($i ~ /mov/) {
            if ($i !~ /normal/){
                sub(/^.*=/, "", $i)
                print $i
            }
        }
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
$ awk -F'"' -f h.awk html
one-hd.mov
another-hd.mov
```

But I **strongly** advice you to use a html-parser for this instead, something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)